# Windows Azure Service Fabric count not start

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-service-fabric

To the point: Having trouble setting up Windows Azure Service fabric. Please help.

System Detail:

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- Windows Azure SDK 2.6 (installed before Service Fabri SDK install)
- SQL Server 2012

[image]

Other errors also appear but those are before trying to start the service. Following is error screen shot when I tried to expand Node view

[image]

**Troubleshooting link available in the SDK tutorial is not helping. I tried with un/installing the SDK but no luck.**

Comment: I had the same problem, tried a lot of things to get it running, but no luck. I ended up creating a new VM with a clean install of Windows, VS 2015 RC and Service Fabric SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try running the following command from an elevated powershell session?

```
if((get-ItemProperty 'hklm:\software\microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\perflib\009' Counter).Counter[0] -eq ''){echo "Corrupt"} if([System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Exists("Service Fabric Actor") -and ![System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories().CategoryName.Contains("Service Fabric Actor")) { echo "Corrupt" }
```

If this command prints out Corrupt, you will need to run 'lodctr /R' to recover the performance counter registry on your system.  Depending on your system, you might need to run lodctr from c:\windows\syswow64 and c:\windows\system32.

Comment: Yes, Corrupt message get printed. And lodctr /R is also not working. Giving "Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2PS C:\windows\system32"

Comment: Hey Premchandra, I think running lodctr from c:\windows\syswow64 should fix your issue.  I updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Premchandra, can you try the steps that Matt outlined? Also this should be fixed in the latest SDK from November, so if you try again please let us know.